# What is the shortest fingerprint of a Curve25519 public key that is secure

Tags: hash, libsodium

My clients have to exchange public keys. To ensure security they are exchanging fingerprints and typing them into the computer by hands.

I want the fingerprints to be as short as possible.

I am using libsodium for encryption, which uses Curve25519. What is the shortest fingerprint I can generate which would still ensure security?

Comment: Note that it might be possible to use a [short-authentication-string (SAS)](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30589/do-low-entropy-fingerprints-actually-make-any-sense/30590#30590) instead of a fingerprint. Since those are not vulnerable to offline attacks, they can be much shorter.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Oh, I did not know that possibility. That is great!